# repeat table header

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to repeat the table header when it spans more then one page, or even detect the page break so I can add the header myself, I'm using Docx4j library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add to the relevant table row (w:tr):

```
<w:trPr>
  <w:tblHeader />
</w:trPr>
```

For how to do this, please see http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/insert-a-tableheader-t237.html

For more on the element (from ISO/IEC 29500-1 1st Edition), you can see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tableheader.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, okay I have done as you wrote on www.docx4java.org, and added String strTrPr = "<w:trPr xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">" + "<w:tblHeader />" + "</w:trPr>"; then tr.setTrPr((TrPr)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(strTrPr)); before TrPr trPr = tr.getTrPr(); but I'm getting an exception javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", local:"trPr"), so what do you think ?

Comment: Try ((TrPr)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(strTrPr, Context.jc, TrPr.class)) or use the approach in the link given above.

Comment: Really, Thank you sooo much Jason for the library and the support, it worked :D, yes I was trying to use the same approach that you wrote on docx4java but when I call tr.getTrPr() without setting it, I was getting null pointer exception.